# Why aren't questions marked as duplicate removed

Tags: discussion

I have seen questions marked with [duplicate] in titles, yet still showing up in search results for both StackOverflow pages and google searches.

What are the reasons for keeping them if the questions are already deemed redundant enough to marked as duplicates?

Comment: ["Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a _signpost_?

Comment: I think I can infer what `signpost` means in this context. Still not clear why some are deleted, yes other are not. What determines which should be left for signpost?

Comment: Score mainly. The reason that *any* duplicates are deleted is because of the auto-deletion mechanism. [If the question is more than 30 days old, has −1 or lower score, no answers and is not locked or it was closed and migrated to a different site then it will be deleted, whether it is a duplicate or not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Comment: Given all these separate resources needed to construct a full answer to my question. I have no idea why my question is being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

We keep them *so that* they can show up in SERPs, where the duplicate targets might not.

In that sense, they are not completely redundant.

A duplicate question *is* redundant if it's unlikely that it will help searchers find the canonical question in situations they otherwise wouldn't have. For example, we don't really need several dozen posts that all say "Notice: Undefined variable..." if they all point to the same root problem.